# Why Div is pushed down to the page

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to style the central big part called "jumpotron" which contains "letters" and "h1". When I try to push "letters" or "h1" lower in the central area vertically it moves the whole "jumpotron" together with the background image. Why does that happen? Why it doesn't respect the fact that "letters" is a child of "jumpotron" so it has to move it's margins inside of "jumpotron"? Also is there a better way to create a big image background for the "jumpotron" from the one I used?

Here's the code:

```
    <body>
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Trunk Club</h2>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>How it Works</li>
        <li>What to Expect</li>
        <li>Stylists</li>
        <li>Log In</li>
        <li><a id="getstarted" href="#">Get Started</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
<div id="jumpotron">
  <div id="letters">
    <h1>Premium Clothing,<br>
      Great Advice,<br>
      Zero Work</h1>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>


@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
body {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}

.container {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 800px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #151e28;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

header h2 {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 15px;
}

nav {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 5px
}

nav li {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    color: #878b85;
    margin-left: 20px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;

}

nav ul li:nth-child(4) {
    border-left: 1px solid #878b85;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    margin-top: -5px;   
}

nav ul li:nth-child(5) {
    border: 1px solid #878b85;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    margin-top: -5px;
}

#getstarted {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #878b85;
}

#getstarted:visited {
    color: #878b85;
}


#jumpotron {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 670px;
    background-image: url(images/Stylist_Product_Exp30-v3.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 100% auto;
}

#letters {
    margin-top: 500px;
}

#jumpotron h1 {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 55px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the padding on #letters to 500, not the margin

Comment: But why? My goal is to understand. Why the background pictures moves together with #letters or h1? Can't understand it since the background picture is applied on "jumpotron".

Comment: You should read up on the CSS box model. The margin is the space outside of the element's border, while the padding is the area within the border. Here's a link for CSS box model http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp